# c# decimal to string with maximum length

Tags: c#, tostring

I have to send a decimal in string format. The maximum length of the string is 15. How can I do this by rounding to the best fit?

eg:

> 1111111111111119 = "111111111111112"
>
> 11111111111111.111 = "11111111111111"
>
> 1.11111111111119 = "1.1111111111112"

Thanks

Comment: What if you have number like this `456456456456464654.6545646` ? You want to eat the characters after index `15` ?

Comment: yes, have to eat. integration with legacy system

Comment: I didn't understand why you want to do that. If you have `12345678901234567890` and you cut it to fit the 15 length, then  you're changing it's value (`123456789012345`), are you sure you want that?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

if you want to cut the string to 15 characters only,

```
decimal sample = 123456789123456789;
string result = sample.ToString().Substring(0, 15); // this cuts it to 15 characters
**returns 123456789123456**
```

if you want to round of from the 15 character.

```
decimal sample = 123456789123456789;
double result2 = Math.Round(sample.ToString().Substring(0, 16));
**returns 123456789123457**
```

Comment: This will throw exception if number is small(results in length less than 15)

Comment: he was asking for a specific task and that's to cut it by 15, he didn't ask how to prevent this and that. An i'm assuming since he is trying to "Cut" by the 15th, he will only do it if its already >15

so he must already have a condition for it. >.>

Comment: Let OP know about the problems. Op may not be knowing this will throw exception may result in process crash too!.

Comment: Funny how you try and solve problems the author's not asking, maybe you should find someone who has a problem like "having an exception while trying to get substring". Maybe you'll be of help there LOLOL.

Comment: Do this kind of code in your production code. One day your code will **LOL** at you. Learn [Defensive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming)

Comment: HAHAHA!, you're really funny, good that you know Defensive Programming, LOLOLOL. Rather than you noting what's missing, go help others, give them every defensive code you know :-D

Comment: Great joke.. ROFL..:))

Answer (score 0):

I found a quite inelegant way of doing this, but it handles your test cases and another edge case I found:

```
static string ToStringOfMaxLength(decimal x) {

    const int maxLength = 15;

    var str = x.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    if(str.Length <= maxLength)
        return str;

    if(str[maxLength] == '.')
        return str.Substring(0, maxLength);
    if(str[maxLength - 1] == '.')
        return str.Substring(0, maxLength - 1);

    var digitsToDisplayExceptLast = str.Substring(0, maxLength - 1);

    var lastDigitToDisplay = CharToInt(str[maxLength - 1]);

    var firstDigitNotDisplayed = CharToInt(str[maxLength]);

    if(firstDigitNotDisplayed >= 5)
        lastDigitToDisplay++;

    return digitsToDisplayExceptLast + lastDigitToDisplay;
}

static int CharToInt(char c) {
    return (int)(c - 48);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should do exactly what you needed (tested on your example values):

```
string ValueString15(decimal value)
{
    while (value >= 1000000000000000M)  // for your first example case
        value /= 10;
    int dotIndex = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).IndexOf('.');
    value = (dotIndex >= 14) ? Math.Round(value) : Math.Round(value, 14 - dotIndex);
    return value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

If you need to deal with negative values (i.e. value < 0), you should also add:

```
|| value <= -100000000000000M
```

to the while condition.